# Showing that the difference between two CDF functions is positive when CDFs are symbolic expressions

Tags: symbolic, expression-test

I'd like to check the sign of a symbolic expression conditional on some predefined assumptions. More specifically, first, I want to assume that the mean and variance of a normally distributed random variable is between 0 and 1. Then I want to show that the probability that this variable is between two values (that are also between 0 and 1) is positive. Here is my code:

```
$Assumptions = {1>kmax>kmin>0,1>m>0,1>sigma>0};
FullSimplify@Positive[CDF[NormalDistribution[m,sigma],kmax]-CDF[NormalDistribution[m,sigma],kmin]]
```

which returns

[image]

Can someone help me understand why Mathematica does not see that this expression is strictly positive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. The question is not really a Mathematica question, nor a Normal distribution question. If $X$ is a continuous random variable with cdf $F(x)$, then by definition $F(x)$ is a non-decreasing function of $x$, and strictly increasing over any positive density. Finally, $P(a<X<b) = F(b)-F(a)$ for $b>a$... and that covers you for everything.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the mathematical proof you provide. However, my end goal is to use Mathematica to conveniently check the signs of other more complex symbolic expressions I have at hand. The fact that Mathematica fails to recognize the positivity of the simple expression above means that it can't help me assess other expressions either.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly says that `Positive` works only for numbers. This explains the output obtained by you. That you want can be done as follows.

```
FunctionMonotonicity[CDF[NormalDistribution[m, sigma], x], x,StrictInequalities -> True]
```

> `1`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that, especially because it seems to work fine in simpler cases such as checking whether kmax-kmin is positive. Do you have any suggestions on how to assess the sign of symbolic expressions with Mathematica in general?

Comment: @elifcansu: Please formulate a more concrete question. What a question, such an answer.

Comment: I mean to ask whether there is a function that performs what Positive[] does but for symbolic expressions. Or if not, is it possible to construct one?

Comment: @elifcansu: I don't know such a function in Mathematica. `FindInstance` may do the job in some cases That's all.